# Expansion of IR Divergent integrals

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, singularities, self-energy

I'm reading this paper about QED counterterms:
[https://southampton.ac.uk/~doug/qft/aqft3.pdf](https://southampton.ac.uk/%7Edoug/qft/aqft3.pdf)
In this paper by calculating the electron self energy we have following expression:
$$\Sigma(p^2,m) = -\frac{\alpha}{2\pi}\left((\gamma \cdot p-4m)\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}-\gamma_E+\operatorname{Ln}(4\pi)\right)+\gamma \cdot p-2m - \\ \int_0^1d\alpha(2(1-\alpha)\gamma \cdot p-4m)\operatorname{Ln}\left(\frac{m^2\alpha^2}{\mu^2}\right)\right)$$
Where $\gamma \cdot p$ denotes $\gamma^\mu p_\mu$. However the last integral ist IV divergent. In the above paper the Integral ist expandet and so we end up with:

$$\Sigma(p^2,m) = \frac{\alpha}{2\pi}\left(3m\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}-\gamma_E+\operatorname{Ln}(4\pi)\right)-m + 2m \int_0^1d\alpha(1-\alpha)\operatorname{Ln}\left(\frac{m^2\alpha^2}{\mu^2}\right)\right) + \frac{\alpha}{2\pi}\left(1-\frac{1}{\epsilon} - \operatorname{Ln}(4\pi) + \gamma_E +2\int_0^1d\alpha(1-\alpha)\operatorname{Ln}\left(\frac{m^2\alpha^2}{\mu^2}\right) +4\int_0^1d\alpha\frac{1-\alpha^2}{\alpha}\right)(\gamma \cdot p-m) + O((\gamma \cdot p-m)^2).$$

I don't now where the integral over $\frac{1-\alpha^2}{\alpha}$
comes and when I compute the above expression I get:

$$\Sigma(p^2,m) = \frac{\alpha}{2\pi}\left(3m\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}-\gamma_E+\operatorname{Ln}(4\pi)\right)+ m + 2m \int_0^1d\alpha\operatorname{Ln}\left(\frac{m^2\alpha^2}{\mu^2}\right)\right) + 
\frac{\alpha}{2\pi}\left(-1-\frac{1}{\epsilon} - \operatorname{Ln}(4\pi) + \gamma_E -2\int_0^1d\alpha(1-\alpha)\operatorname{Ln}\left(\frac{m^2\alpha^2}{\mu^2}\right)\right).$$

So there are other Factors which are that not correspond with the expression in the paper. So I don't now if the expression in the paper is correct or if I have made a mistake. The other question is how we can extract the IV divergence out of the integral. I think these questions are relatet each other

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.